# why finger of hands and feet become wrinkled due to to water?

Tags: human-biology, skin

Mostly due to bathing or washing clothes our finger become wrinkled what was the reason behind it??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few hypothesis around it, but it is known that its associated with the function of distal nerves of the hands and feet. I suggest reading this short case for a glimpse at this - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2464382/

Also another tip I can give is that professional swimming athletes for example, eventually experiment an adaptation process in which this wrinkling reaction diminishes due to being exposed to the same stimuli repeatedly and for long periods of time.

Comment: I am not talking about swimming, it it different thing I am simply asked about how to prevent this?

Comment: Mmm I thought you wanted to understand the biological  behind it :(

Comment: @Anum In your question you do not mention about this. And therefore it will be closed as a duplicate.